# Bound on Av/v by eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$. I want to bound $\frac{|Av|}{|v|}$ from above. I thought that the upper bound will be equal to the largest eigenvalue, but somehow it turned out not to be true: example I found is $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&5\\1&6 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v = (13,20)^T$. Then $Av = (113,133)^T$, $|v| \approx 23.85$, $|Av| \approx 174.52$ and $\frac{|Av|}{|v|} \approx 7.32$, while eigenvalues of $A$ are $\phi^4,\ \phi^{-4}$ (bigger one is equal to $\approx 6.85$).

So my questions are:

1. Why geometric intuition, that eigenvector is the vector whose length increases the most, fails here?
2. How to obtain some other bound on $\frac{|Av|}{|v|}$? My hypothesis is to take square root of the largest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ and it intuitively works but, well, my intuition had already failed once.

Comment: This property is only true for **symmetric** matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value Basically, your 2. is correct, but we usually look at $A^TA$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $v$ which maximizes $\frac{|Av|}{|v|}$ is the same as maximizing $\frac{|Av|^2}{|v|^2}$. Now $|Av|^2$ is a *quadratic form* when expanded out. So the problem is the equivalent to maximizing some quadratic form $q(v)$ subject to the condition $|v|=1$.

Quadratic forms, like $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ in two variables, are nicely behaved functions whose contours are ellipses or hyperbolas. On the unit circle/sphere, they take a maximum and minimum on perpendicular axes. (These are the eigenvectors of $A^TA$.)

[image]

The eigenvectors of $A$ will be some 'random' directions, not necessarily perpendicular, that have nothing to do with these max/min directions, unless the matrix $A$ is symmetric so that its eigenvectors agree with those of $A^TA$.

Here are two specific examples that illustrate this. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $v=(x,y)$. Then $|Av|^2=y^2$ which has max/min directions $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$; but it has only one eigenvector $(1,0)$ with eigenvalue $0$.

Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-20\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Its quadratic form is elliptical, $(x-20y)^2+y^2=x^2-40xy+401y^2\approx 401y^2$, whose perpendicular max/min directions are $(-0.05, 0.999), (0.999, 0.05)$; yet the eigenvectors are $(1,0)$ and $(1,0.1)$, totally unrelated. What's going on here is that the eigenvectors are pointing in almost the same direction, yet their eigenvalues are opposite in sign; the direction which is being multiplied out the most is being almost cancelled by another close-by eigenvector. The maximum is in an almost perpendicular direction.

Note that for any given quadratic form $q(v)=v^TSv$, there are many matrices such that $A^TA=S$.